# Will loop constructs become obsolete?

Tags: programming-languages, python, loops

By loop constructs I mean for… and while… constructs with nested statements.

Currently I am coding a tool in Python and decided out of curiosity not to use the regular loops - and rely on filter/map/reduce instead. E.g. now I have code like:

```
fields = filter(None, map(parse_field, struct_decl.get_children()))
```

So far it works out fairly well and I like the way I am now designing the code - I have a clean-cut functions (though sometimes I need to use a lambda) and I do think that the resulting code might be more efficient (e.g. the iterations are more naturally independent making them more parallelizable). And I only have to increase indentation for conditionals (though I am thinking about avoiding them as well)

These new functions are not unique to Python - e.g. C++ had std::foreach for ages.

I wonder if traditional loops will eventually be frown upon in mainstream languages, similar to `goto`?

Comment: As a side note, check out Haskell, or another functional language that doesn't have language-level support for loops outside of recursion. You might find it interesting. The prevailing style in those languages is to do precisely what you're doing in Python (only I expect the resulting code looks cleaner in languages designed for it).

Comment: @KChaloux: Scheme is that way as well. I still have to fight the desire to do things recursively.

Comment: For reference, your code might look like **this** in Haskell:

`let fields = filter (not . isNothing) $ map parseField $ children structDecl`

Comment: @KChaloux I know that this is called functional programming - I'm really curious about mainstream languages eventually embracing these construct as a "recommended" way  to operate on sequences. E.g. goto is still there pretty much - but it is frowned upon.

Comment: *Maybe*, in situations where a `foreach`-type loop iterates over a collection and the operation done to each item can be easily abstracted out, but I think loops that simply go from *start* to *n*, it's probably easier to use an old-fashioned `for` loop instead of something recursive or using map/reduce. I'd also argue that teaching a simple `for` loop that prints someone's name *n* times on the screen is much easier than teaching something that does it recursively (or using map/reduce, or something).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I know that since Java5 introduced for…each loop, I use "for (i = …; i<…; i++) loops really sparingly - turns out I needed to iterate over collection most often. Note that Python has a "range" function that returns a sequence - so you iterate with foreach (or use something like map) on that collection.

Comment: @Eugene: Me too, but mostly I do enterprise web applications now, so yeah, it's all looping through collections - there's very little numerical stuff. I seem to recall that waaaay back when I was doing a lot more math/graphics -oriented programming, there was just as much looping on numbers as collections. I still use `while` loops a fair bit though and I don't see them as easily replaceable by `foreach`.

Comment: btw: iterator pattern (ie. foreach) is in a slightly different category from filter/map constructs. It's still imperative.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do these languages/constructs process two parallel collections/array, especially where the "index" of a member in one dictates the position in the other? Example: two arrays that I want to process matching elements on their index in the array - iow arrayA[i] and arrayB[i] should be processed together. `For each` over either array is not going to cut it as I would have to maintain a current index myself to access the other array. Am I simply missing a construct or data structure that is available for this in more functional languages?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner The opposite could be argued: only when you actually *need* an index, should you use a `for` (though, mapi provides an index).

Comment: @MarjanVenema In C#, Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(i => arrayA[i]... /*...*/ arrayB[i]...). Basically, you can select (map) over the index, and not the items in the collection.

Comment: If you haven't already, do also take a look at the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) (part of the standard library) as well. Get to grips with generators and generator expressions, etc. Loops still have their place, however, some things are naturally more readable and more expressive with a good loop construct.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: In Python, you could write `for (a, b) in zip(arrayA, arrayB):`.

Comment: I would add that python seems to prefer an explicit for loop to reduce, as reduce has been moved to the functools module in python 3. The what's new in python 3 page explicitly states that 99% of the time an explicit for loop is more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say your assumption is correct. Mainstream languages pick up more and more functional features, and if you have constructs like higher order functions and lambdas/closures, the tasks concerning "looping" become just ordinary functions.

A good example for this development is Scala: It has `while` (mainly used for implementing fast library functions), but its `for`is not the "traditional" C-style one, but actually a for-comprehension similar to Haskell's, which can filter, map and "flatMap". Additionally collection classes have a bunch of methods like `filter`, `map`, `foreach` and more difficult stuff like `flatMap` or several versions of folding. Java 8 will introduce some similar features for collections (but of course not as much as Scala did).

While its not clear if traditional imperative loops will really disappear, their importance will drop considerably. The advantages are clear:

- You can think on a "higher level" in terms of collections and their transformations, not about something like loop variables
- Functions like `foreach`or `map` are less error-prone, as they encapsulate behavior, preventing e.g. one-off errors completely
- Formerly awkward operations like looping simultaneously though collections become easier  (`zip`, `zipWith`), following the same functional style
- Lazy collections (e.g. streams), which are potentially infinite data structures, don't work too well with traditional loops; the paradigm of "transformation" is much more natural for them than "looping"
- You already mentioned parallelization